# Scientific Notation formatting

Tags: python, formatting, scientific-notation

How can get following formatting (input values are always less than 0.1):

```
> formatting(0.09112346)
0.91123E-01
> formatting(0.00112346)
0.11234E-02
```

and so on.

I am looking for some elegant solution. I am already using a custom function given below:

```
def formatting(x, prec=5):
    tup    = x.as_tuple()
    digits = list(tup.digits[:prec])
    dec    = ''.join(str(i) for i in digits)
    exp    = x.adjusted()
    return '0.{dec}E{exp}'.format(dec=dec, exp=exp)
```

Comment: You mean how to get a specific notation when printing a number?

Comment: i think yes. (i am not very clear on the concept of "specific notation")

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I mean printing the number with different notation, like exponential notation, or specifying only a certain amount of digits after the comma, and so on...

Answer (score 18):

You can use the [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format) function. [The format specification](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) mentions it there:

> 'E' - Exponent notation. Same as 'e' except it uses an upper case ‘E’ as the separator character.

```
>>> print('{:.5E}'.format(0.09112346))
9.11235E-02
>>> print('{:.5E}'.format(0.00112346))
1.12346E-03
```

---

However it isn't quite like the output you have in your answer. If the above is not satisfactory, then you might use a custom function to help (I'm not the best at this, so hopefully it's ok):

```
def to_scientific_notation(number):
    a, b = '{:.4E}'.format(number).split('E')
    return '{:.5f}E{:+03d}'.format(float(a)/10, int(b)+1)

print(to_scientific_notation(0.09112346))
# 0.91123E-01
print(to_scientific_notation(0.00112346))
# 0.11234E-02
```

Comment: yes, sorry but, that's not the output I am looking for. I am already using a custom function (in my answer)

Comment: @ARK4579 Um, sorry, did you read the whole answer? The 2nd part gives the format you asked for (0.91123E-01 and 0.11234E-02) or am I missing something?

Comment: yes, it does. thanks. :) but i am already using a custom function. :)

Answer (score 11):

In Python 3.6+, you could also use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals). For example:

```py
In [31]: num = 0.09112346

In [32]: f'{num:.5E}'
Out[32]: '9.11235E-02'
```

It uses the same syntax as `str.format()`, given in the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) section.

---

**Edit**:

The `f'{num:.5E}'` will always return the number in the [*normalized* scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), meaning that the absolute value of `m` (=significand) in the returned number `[m]E[n]` is always between 1 and 10.

If you want to force the absolute value of the significand (`m`) to be between 0.1 and 1 (0.1 <= |m| < 1.0), then you have to use a custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another syntax option to format normalized scientific notation:

```py
number = 0.09112346
string = '%.5E' % number
# 9.11235E-02
```