# How to convert a float into format of 0.####e# in python

Tags: python, floating-point, scientific-notation

Using python, I am trying to print floats in the format of 0.####e#.  For example, 1234.56 is converted to 0.123456e4 or .321 is converted to 0.321e0 etc. I am surprised that an extensive search has not produced any sample code for this exercise. As far as I can tell, neither [Display a decimal in scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913532/display-a-decimal-in-scientific-notation) or [stackoverflow.com/questions/53274821/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53274821/scientific-notation-formatting-in-python) address converting a number like 1234.56 into 0.123456e4.

If possible, I would like to use the python f-string to do the conversion.  But any solution is very welcomed.

Comment: The linked answer isn't a direct duplicate, but this one is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53274821/scientific-notation-formatting-in-python

Comment: Neither one of the suggested answers addresses my question.  I  see nothing in those answers that takes a number like 1234.56 and convert it to 0.123456e4.

Comment: There isn't a straight-up f string that gives this exact format, the closest you could get is 1.2345e+3, but the answer I linked shows how to make a function using two f strings. You should be able to alter it a tiny bit to get your preferred format